CSS local svg icon color
I am trying to setup some custom svg icons like this
<i class="my-svg-icon"></i>

I have the svg displayed but cannot adjust the color
.my-svg-icon {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    color: red !important;
    content: url('/mysvg.svg');
}

I have set the stroke in the svg to be currentColor and the fill is none.

You can't change the style of an SVG that is not used as an actual SVG in the HTML.

Instead of using the i tag, try using the svg tag. By using the svg tag you can add a color property like this:


<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g color="green">
    <rect width="50" height="50" fill="currentcolor" />
    <circle
      r="25"
      cx="70"
      cy="70"
      stroke="currentcolor"
      fill="none"
      stroke-width="5" />
  </g>
</svg>



Source
